# 'Run' or 'Operate' for a business related sentence

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to decide between two sentences but not sure which one fits the most. I am going to use this sentence inside the 'About Us' section of the company.

Option 1

> Company A also runs two hotels.

Option 2

> Company A also operates two hotels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose 'Run'.

While both are ok, I would say that 'operate' has come to imply a more physical interaction - using your hands to make something function in a certain way. Thus, one might *operate* a machine.

'Run' is more often used to imply a less physical involvement. For this context, 'run' and 'manage' are more likely to be considered synonymous than 'run' and 'operate', given common usage.

I say again, a dictionary will tell you that both of these sentences are fine and I agree that you could choose either. I recommend using 'run' based solely on common usage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought this, too and that's why I asked the question in fist place. I would go ahead and use **run** but then I come across that somebody else used **operate** instead. As far as I've known so far, **operate** is used mostly in situation which requires physical movement as you explained.

Comment: I would say 'Company X operates IN place Y' to mean that they are active there, they have branches there and so on. In your example though, where you are referring directly to their involvement in specific branches/franchises, I would go with 'run' for the reasons given in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Either sentence is fine, I'd say, although "operates" might be a touch more formal.