# "Operate" on fossil fuels vs "Run" on fossil fules

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, differences

Example sentence:

> Since our obsolete power stations still **run** on fossil fuels, they emit
>   substantial amounts of greenhouse gases.

Would it be more formal, if it is changed into the following form:

> Since our obsolete power stations still **operate** on fossil fuels,
>   they emit substantial amounts of greenhouse gases.

Which one of the verbs sounds better in this context, or would you recommend some other verbs? I assume that to *run on* is a rather informal expression.

Comment: See related thread, [_'Run' or 'Operate' for a business related sentence_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29792)

Comment: "Operate" is a hair stuffier than "run", if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Neither.  Something that is *obsolete* is no longer in use, so it neither runs nor operates.  In response to the question itself about "runs" vs. "operates," write to your audience.  If this is something for technical readers, say, "operates."  If this is a business communication, the rule of thumb in business is to never use a $5 word where a 5 cent word will do, so say, "runs."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Not necessarily the case (regarding *obsolete*); see Merriam-Webster [definition 1(b)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolete).

Answer (score 2):

> They run on coal.
>
> They are coal-fired.

There are some other, more obscure, variations, but "run" is perfectly legitimate and hardly colloquial in this case. Use it boldly and lavishly, and pay no heed to those who would cavil at it: folks of that sort would cavil at anything.